# Define regex for string with one letter and one number in Java

Tags: java, regex

I need to validate that the string contains exactly one letter as the first character and a number as the second character. So the string should look like this: `D8`, `Z6`, ...

I've tried using the following regex:

```
^[A-Za-z][1-8]$
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. Can anybody see where I'm going wrong?

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work for me?

```
System.out.println("D6".matches("^[a-zA-Z][1-8]$")); // True
System.out.println("D8".matches("^[a-zA-Z][1-8]$")); // True
System.out.println("D9".matches("^[a-zA-Z][1-8]$")); // False
```

Perhaps the problem that exists is that you have extra whitespace..

```
System.out.println(" D8 ".trim().matches("^[a-zA-Z][1-8]$")); // True
```

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be working. I had to split the string before and I think that messed up my string. I added a trim() to it and now it works just fine. Interesting.